# Handle mismatching shape for dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website with click button of selenium so i scrape table of many page : 
* the pattern of table is the same for almost every table 
suppose we have a list : this is the header of my table it contains 5 columns i put it as a static typing

```
header = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

and a corpus as a list too with 5 columns like :

```
["abc", "edf", "dfk", "kkk""...", 
 "...", "...", "...", "...",
"...", "...", "...", "..."]
```

here's my problem sometimes the columns corresponding to header "b", is missing. 
so when i'm building my dataFrame like pd.DataFrame(line, columns = header) sometimes len(line) == line(header) so it's ok sometimes not
here's my code when it's not working

```
def function(parameters) : 
    ....
    web scraping 
    ....
    try : 
        df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns = header)
        return df
    except ValueError :
        print("table and header columns shape mismatch") 
    else : 
        for line in table : # table is corpus list
            line.insert(1, "None") # i know that every missing columns is the 2nd one so i add None to add that missing columns
            # in theory shape must match so i build df
        df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns = header)
        return df
```

But i still had columns mismatching in error, so i would like to know where's my error or a alternative way.
I hope this clear. Thanks.

Comment: what is the shape of table before creating the df

Comment: shape of table i said 5 columns for header and table, but sometimes table = 4

Comment: Why are you inserting in just first position?`line.insert(1, "None")`

Comment: because sometime the columns B (only B) is missing if len 4 != 5 mismatch i got value error

Comment: I am confused if entire second column in missing then remove the corresponding header. If some are missing then add condition if missing then only add None this way if the value is present then length of inner list will be 6 which is also not desirerable

Comment: The entire second columns missing sometimes and sometimes not it's written  I scrape multiple web page with same pattern except that column

Comment: try checking what will happen if data is correct and nothing is missing

Comment: That's work fine just as I said... That why I put an exception in code